SAP B1 DiAPI does not load
We had to reinstall our System and I we need to run our old PowerShell scripts. However, it seems like PowerShell does not load the DiAPI correctly.
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("C:\Program Files\SAP\SAP Business One\SAPBusinessOneSDK.dll")

A function like [SAPbouiCOM.SboGuiApi]::new does not reveal the available functions as it did before or does with other methods.
Our previous system was Windows 10 and our new system is on Windows 11. Are there any new security settings or may we have forgotten to install any necessary SAP files?
Powershell runs in 64bit and I have installed both versions of the DI-API.

By default SAP B1 SDK is installed at this location: "C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP\SAP Business One SDK\Lib"
I think you need to install SAP B1 SDK or adjust your path to it.
